# How to use an array as type double?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm first using a scanner for user input and then calculating the mean.

I keep getting the error "lossy conversion from double to int".

It works when I use everything as type integer, but when calculating the mean it just converts it to an integer and it most of the time the mean isn't a whole number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateMean {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner enterValues = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of values. ");
        double n = enterValues.nextDouble();
        double[] set = new double[n];
        System.out.println("Enter values.");

        for(double x=0; x<n; x++) {
           set[x] = enterValues.nextDouble();
        }

        double sum = 0;

        for(double cnt=0; cnt < set.length; cnt++) {
            sum += set[cnt];
        }

        double mean = sum / n;
        System.out.println("The average of the values is " + mean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if the array element type is `double`, the *index* type is `int`. So your `n`, `x`, and `cnt` should be `int`, as you're using them to index into the array.

See the comment markers below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateMean {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner enterValues = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of values. ");

        int n = enterValues.nextInt();               // <== They won't give you 6.3 values, will they?
        double[] set = new double[n];

        System.out.println("Enter values.");

        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {                // <==
            set[x] = enterValues.nextDouble();
        }

        double sum = 0;

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < set.length; cnt++) { // <==
            sum += set[cnt];
        }

        double mean = sum / n;

        System.out.println("The average of the values is " + mean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate the `loop` and in `size` of `array` use `int` not double like:

```
   int n = enterValues.nextInt();              
   double[] set = new double[n];
  ...
 for(int x=0; x<n; x++)
 ....
 for(int cnt=0; cnt < set.length; cnt++)
```

Here is the code

```
 package newPack;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CalculateMean
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  Scanner enterValues = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the number of values. ");


  int n = enterValues.nextInt();
  double[] set = new double[n];

  System.out.println("Enter values.");
   for(int x=0; x<n; x++)
   {
     set[x] = enterValues.nextDouble();
    }
   double sum = 0;

  for(int cnt=0; cnt < set.length; cnt++)
    {
    sum += set[cnt];
    }

  double mean = sum / n;

  System.out.println("The average of the values is " + mean);

   }

 }
```